# No distance left to run

Tags: meaning

*No distance left to run.*

Can you help me with understanding of the meaning of the above phrase? In which context is it used?

Comment: Is it supposed to have a special idiomatic meaning? And what do you mean by "in which context is it used?" If it's sane and grammatical English it can happen to be found everywhere.

Comment: Means nothing to me, as it stands. I mean, I understand the words & the implication, but it's not any kind of common idiom. "No *place* left to run" is, however, quite common. [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=No+distance+left+to+run%2C+no+place+left+to+run&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20place%20left%20to%20run%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: These questions are much easier to answer when context is provided. Where did you hear/read this?

Answer (score 1):

*No distance left to run* could mean "The race is over, I've reached the finish line".

No food left to eat = All of the food has been consumed.

No distance left to run = All of the distance has been traversed.

In those sentences:

to eat = to be eaten.

to run = to be run.

Passive infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

It is the burden and title of a song by the band Blur, and the title of a film about the band.

It has no idiomatic meaning that I know of. To say you have such-and-such a distance 'left to go/travel/walk/run' means that you are presently at that distance from your projected endpoint; so to have **no** distance left to run means you have arrived at the endpoint.

In the song the line seems to refer to the end of a romantic relationship; the choice of *run* suggests either a competition for the estranged lover's favor or (more likely) a sense on the singer's part that he has been in some sense 'running' to keep up with her (her demands or her will to move the relationship in a particular direction or something of that sort) and that he is now wholly exhausted by the effort.